# How do I fix the DoS String#hash vulnerability for ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2009.10?

Tags: ruby, ddos, ruby-enterprise-edition

The problem is described [here](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2011/12/28/denial-of-service-attack-was-found-for-rubys-hash-algorithm/).

There have been patches for 1.8, JRuby and later version of ree, but I can't find anything for this version.

I tried applying this [patch](https://gist.github.com/1535569).

But compiling fails with an error that doesn't make sense since there are no changes to the compiler directives that I can see:

```
gcc -g -Os -fno-strict-aliasing -DRUBY_EXPORT -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -I. -I. -c st.c
st.c:230:49: error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter
make: *** [st.o] Error 1
```

Comment: What does `st.c` look like around line 230 after patching?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/1560362 -- line 11 in the gist is line 230 in the code file.

Comment: Here is the whole file: https://gist.github.com/1560433

Comment: I don't see anything in that patch the would mess up line 230, maybe something in `limits.h` is causing trouble. Try removing `#include <limits.h>` and replacing CHAR_BIT with 8.

Comment: That worked to get past st.c, but it runs into other problems in random.c: https://gist.github.com/1565567.  Those constants are defined in ruby.h in 1.8.7p-357, but not in the ree-2009.10 source.

Comment: I stole a couple of definitions from the 357 ruby.h and it built: https://gist.github.com/1565618.  Now to see if it actually works!  Thanks!  Post an answer so I can accept it and you can give you the reputation love.

Comment: Thanks but I didn't really solve your problem so I don't deserve much, you could post a link to your version of the patch and answer it yourself though :)